# Unable to access the member variables from second parent class in multiple inheritance Python

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, super, abstraction

I am learning multiple inheritance in Python. I have two parent classes Robot and Human. They are being inherited by Cyborg class. I can access the member variable in first class i.e, Robot but unable to access the variables in second BaseClass named *Human*.

Here is my code.

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC

class Robot(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.computation_level = 70

    @abstractmethod
    def vacuum(self):
        pass

class Human(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.feelings_level = 60

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self):
        pass

class Cyborg(Robot, Human):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Cyborg, self).__init__()

    def vacuum(self):
        print("nothing new in vacuum")

    def run(self):
        print("nothing new in run")


h_obj = Cyborg()
h_obj.vacuum()
h_obj.run()
print(h_obj.computation_level)
print(h_obj.feelings_level)
```

It returns the following output

```
nothing new in vacuum
nothing new in run
70
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oop.py", line 49, in <module>
    print(h_obj.feelings_level)
AttributeError: 'Cyborg' object has no attribute 'feelings_level'
```

I have also checked output of *Cyborg.mro()* which is

```
[<class '__main__.Cyborg'>, <class '__main__.Robot'>, <class '__main__.Human'>, <class 'abc.ABC'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Is there any way to access the member variables of second parent class in this case, *Human* class.

Thanks

Comment: `Cyborg.__init__()` only called the inherited method on *one* of its parent classes.  For `super()` to work right in the presence of multiple inheritance, you have to use it in *every* class, even the base classes where it doesn't appear to be needed.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper. It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

It maybe of help anyone else, here is the working code.
Thanks to @jsonharper

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC
class Human(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Human, self).__init__()
        self.feelings_level = 60

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self):
        print("hey ")

class Robot(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Robot, self).__init__()
        self.computation_level = 70

    @abstractmethod
    def vacuum(self):
        print("vaccum")

class Cyborg(Robot, Human):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Cyborg, self).__init__()

    def vacuum(self):
        print("nothing new in vacuum")

    def run(self):
        print("nothing new in run")


h_obj = Cyborg()
h_obj.vacuum()
h_obj.run()
print(h_obj.computation_level)
print(h_obj.feelings_level)
```